# CSS reverting to default styles

Tags: css

A fellow developer has set the following css rule, which must remain in place.

```
* {
    border: medium none;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This removes the border from SELECT and INPUT fields and makes them look less than ideal. If I remove the border style in firebug then the fields look normal again. Which css rules must I add to revert back to the default styles set by the browser?

Edit: these are the styles I'm trying to revert to (on my computer):

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [456bereastreet.com](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single-option/icab-3-osx.png))</sub>

Comment: for a cross-browser solution, you can't *add* styles and revert form elements to normal. the `*` selector is a CSS code-smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your fellow developer was attempting to do was create his own reset (similar to Yahoo Reset, etc). But since he's declaring * instead of specific elements, it removes the border from everything.

You can work around this though and still get the browser's default border back on form elements by changing the * to your most common elements (sans form elements) - it's a bit ugly, but it does what you're looking for:

```
a,abbr,acronym,address,b,blockquote,body,br,caption,dd,div,dl,dt,em,fieldset,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,html,i,img,label,legend,li,link,menu,ol,p,pre,small,span,strong,table,td,th,tr,u,ul
{
    border: medium none;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, I only did the most common elements, there's a few stray ones that were not included but are pretty specific - so if you find something bugging out, check that it's tag is in the list. :)

Comment: I have a similar problem. While creating embed codes, I need to reset the style to the browser original, even when it has been set otherwise. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure about resetting to original. You might want to change the values to 'auto'.

Answer (score 1):

Add these:

```
select, input {
 border: solid 1px; /* or whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: Nope this just ads a black line.

Comment: You need to set the color to whatever you wish to see. `border: solid 1px [color]`

Comment: As I said above, on a mac a select doesn't simply have a line around it.

Comment: I don't have a mac to play around but the idea is you modify it as you wish. If you don't want a border, then the `*` should suffice. I thought you're trying to add the border.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need to set the new values. There is no `reset` value.

If you want to add a border, set the new border style. Or remove the style you posted.

Comment: Which border style? On the Mac that I'm working on, a SELECT does not just have a line around it.

Comment: @stef: Did you try setting a border style for `select`?

Comment: yep. See screenshot I posted in OP